# Issue tracking for individual branches in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

When using GitLab's issue tracker, it seems that I cannot mark a specific branch that an issue affects. I'd like to be able to e.g. show only the issues that are related to a specific feature branch. Is there any way to do this?